# R Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘DNAcopy’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):

Tags: r

I have installed an R package in my Macbook (Big Sur), but I am getting error when I use `library(packagename)`. I have uninstalled the R and then reinstalled it, but it is still giving me same error. I am wondering if there are any PATH settings I need to do.

```
> BiocManager::install("DNAcopy", force = TRUE)
Bioconductor version 3.16 (BiocManager 1.30.19), R 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
Installing package(s) 'DNAcopy'
trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.16/bioc/bin/macosx/contrib/4.2/DNAcopy_1.72.1.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 510684 bytes (498 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 498 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/h1/01m4_1gn65g63hvbv15tq7000000gr/T//RtmpEOBgrr/downloaded_packages
> library(DNAcopy)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘DNAcopy’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/DNAcopy/libs/DNAcopy.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/DNAcopy/libs/DNAcopy.so, 6): Symbol not found: __gfortran_os_error_at
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/DNAcopy/libs/DNAcopy.so
  Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/DNAcopy/libs/DNAcopy.so
```

I would really appreciate any help.

I have tried re-insattling the packages as well as R.